# Autohomeomorphism of the unit disk which is constant on the boundary, and which takes 0 to a prescribed point

Tags: general-topology

Let $D^n$ be the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm looking for a homeomorphism of $D^n$ to itself which is the identity on the boundary, and takes the origin to a given point $z$ in its interior. I can visualize such a function as "shifting around the mass" within $D^n$, but I can't seem to write one down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map the rays starting at $z$ to the rays starting at the origin. Each ray is identified by its point on the boundary.

Comment: for a unit vector $x$ and $t\in[0,1]$ you can use $tx\mapsto z+t(x-z$)